# Some keys are not working on a new keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have read similar problems on the website, and one solution was always to try a new keyboard. But this is a new keyboard and I just bought and installed it right now. It's my first time to open my laptop, so I don't know what might have gone wrong. The keys that are not working are

- <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>
- <kbd>\</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrows
- <kbd>Space</kbd> bar

For completeness, although I guess it is irrelevant, my touchpad is not working either now.

Comment: Yo haven't connected the cable properly?

Comment: All other keys are working and I opened the laptop again and disconnected and reconnected it again, so I guess I connected it right.

Comment: I have to ask… since you are replacing the keyboard, I will assume something was wrong with the last one. Are the same issues (keys not working) the same issues you had previously, or are they different issues? If they are the same issues, then it may be a corrupt keyboard driver. As noted in the answer, the best test is to plug in a USB keyboard and see if you experience the same issues. If the same issues appear, then I would suggest replacing the keyboard driver.

Comment: @JohnG I had similar problems with the old one, but with different keys. it was mostly the left half of the letters like ASDFZXCV and the space bar. I don't remember if the other keys were working with the old one. But the letters are working now.

I have a USB keyboard and everything works fine with it.

Comment: If the USB keyboard works correctly, then unfortunately this points to the keyboard in the laptop as the problem. I would double check to make sure you have it connected properly.

Comment: @JohnG so it's better to replace it again?

Comment: As a tech… it wouldn’t be the first time I ordered something and it was DOA (Dead on Arrival). Contact the seller and they should replace it.

Comment: ok, I will contact them and hope they will understand the problem. Thank you!

Comment: When you used the OSK, did the same keys malfunctioned too?
Or did they work fine? 
And to be clear, you mean, you wireless keyboard you connect with via USB, works fine, totally correct, no problems?
If that's the case, it's definitely your built-in laptop keyboard. Attaching that flat cable can be very tricky.
If you re-assemble the laptop to the point when the keyboard needs to be plugged in and you take it to a shop, 
they will often do that for you without any charge if you go when it's not busy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect an external keyboard to see if your laptop is the problem.

Comment: didn't get you. It's a laptop keyboard, not a Bluetooth one.

Comment: I was thinking of a USB keyboard, but okay.